# Simple way to extract date from text in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, text

The excerpt from data:

Givent the following example of pandas dataframe:

```
df = 
       index              date
        7838      2012 January
        7790      2012 January
        7853    2015 September
        7889        2016 March
        7928      2015 October
        7847      1999 January
        7884      2006 January
        7826      1992 January
```

Is there a simple (and pythonic) way to convert free text into a standard date time variable? Something like:

```
df = 
           index              date
            7838        2012-01-01
            7790        2012-01-01
            7853        2015-09-01
            7889        2016-03-01
            7928        2015-10-01
            7847        1999-01-01
            7884        2006-01-01
            7826        1992-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pd.to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert from text to date type. You can glean the appropriate date types from this [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y %B')
```

Answer (score 2):

[`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) handles this fine without any specific format specifier:

```
In [83]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

Out[83]:
0   2012-01-01
1   2012-01-01
2   2015-09-01
3   2016-03-01
4   2015-10-01
5   1999-01-01
6   2006-01-01
7   1992-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```